# mongoose sorting sub document and return sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

`persons` collection:

```
{ 
    name: "jhon",
    msgs: {
        chat_one: [
            {id: 1234, msg: "hi", date: "18/05/2018"},
            {id: 1234, msg: "hello", date: "19/05/2018"}
        ],
        chat_two: [
            {id: 1234, msg: "hi", date: "18/05/2018"},
            {id: 1234, msg: "hello", date: "19/05/2018"}
        ]
    }
}
```

How to query using mongoose and get data like below.

- sort on date.
- And return `chat_one` messages of a single person.

> ```
> {
>   chat_one: [
>     {id: 1234, msg: "hello", date: "19/05/2018"},
>     {id: 1234, msg: "hi", date: "18/05/2018"}
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: the date is stored as String?

Comment: No its a date object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your new update and requirement below is the aggregation to retrieve only `chat_one` messages.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: "jhon" }},
  { $unwind: "$msgs.chat_one" },
  { $sort: { "msgs.chat_one.date": -1 }},
  { $group: { _id: "$name", chat: { $push: "$msgs.chat_one" }}},
  { $project: { _id: 0 }} // To remove `_id`
])
```

**Output:**

```
[{
  "chat": [
    { "date": "19/05/2018", "id": 1234, "msg": "hello" },
    { "date": "18/05/2018", "id": 1234, "msg": "hi" }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via aggregation like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: "jhon" }},
  { $unwind: "$msgs" },
  { $sort: { "msgs.date": -1 }},
  { $group: { _id: "$name", msgs: { $addToSet: "$msgs" }}},
  { $project: { _id: 0 }}
])
```

You can see it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/twvV_rqUUyu)

The idea is to `$match` first on the name then `$unwind` so we can `$sort` on the date and then `$group` and `$project` to get to the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for solution.  Actually my requirement is different. Please check question Just now I have updated.